# Spark Java IllegalArgumentException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler declares multiple JSON fields named _listeners

Tags: java, post, spark-java

I'm developing a simple project using Java Spark, and at the moment I'm trying to implement a little RESTful service. I have this post method:

```
post("/users", (request, response) -> {
        response.type("application/json");
        User user = new Gson().fromJson(request.body(),User.class);
        userService.addUser(user);
        return new Gson().toJson(response);
    });
```

I'm using postman to specify the body of the request:

```
{   "id": "1012", 
"name": "Mac",
"lastname": "Mason1",
"email": "email"
}
```

And the User class is:

```
 public class User {

public int id;
public String name;
public String lastname;
public String email;

public User (int id, String name, String lastname, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Whenever I try to do a post request, the following error pops up:

```
ERROR spark.http.matching.GeneralError - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler declares multiple JSON fields 
named _listeners
```

Comment: Is it expected that you are trying to serialize the `response` object as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new Gson().toJson(response);
```

This code is trying to serialize the `response` object as JSON. This is probably a typo (surely you meant `return new Gson().toJson(user);`, or something entirely different instead) and fails because of the way Gson tries to recursively serialize all fields in the class hierarchy of `response`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've followed a tutorial where they did this toJson(response) and thought it was ok. Thanks for the explanation